SQL query execution in nodejs using "msnodesqlv8" module
Issue with handling multiple SQL queries in Node.js with msnodesqlv8.
I have encountered an interesting problem while working with Node.js and msnodesqlv8 for SQL Server interactions.
Here is the relevant code - controller - discussion part:
const discussionPostQuery = `
    INSERT INTO Community_Discussion 
    (UserID, Title, Content, Image, Likes, Comment, Tag, Visibility, Reference, ResourceUrl, AuthAdd, AddOnDt, delStatus) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, GETDATE(), 0); 
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertedId;
`;

const discussionPost = await queryAsync(conn, discussionPostQuery, [
    rows[0].UserID, title, content, image, likes, comment, tags, visibility, threadReference, url, rows[0].Name, 0
]);

const lastInsertedIdQuery = `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS LastInsertedId;`;
const lastInsertedId = await queryAsync(conn, lastInsertedIdQuery);

console.log(discussionPost);
console.log(lastInsertedId, discussionPost);

queryAsync function:
export async function queryAsync(conn, query, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query(query, params, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log(results);
            resolve(results);
        });
    });
}

The problem: when I execute this code, the output at console.log() in the "Controller - Discussion" part is as follows:
[]
[{ LastInsertedId: null }]
[]

However, when I check the console output within the queryAsync function, I get:
[]
[{ LastInsertedId: 57 }]
[{ LastInsertedId: null }]

The issue: the expected result is the LastInsertedId from the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() query, which appears correctly in the queryAsync function's output ([{ LastInsertedId: 57 }]).
However, when I attempt to retrieve it in the controller, the data seems to be lost, and I get [{ LastInsertedId: null }].
This issue occurs between the console logs of queryAsync and the controller, leading to data loss that I need to fix.
What I tried
I attempted to break the query into nested calls but still encountered the same issue.
